# Advantage of TensorWatch over TensorBoardX?

Tags: logging, data-visualization, pytorch, tensorboard

I work with PyTorch.

**I was wondering what's the advantage of [TensorWatch](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorwatch) over [TensorBoardX](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboardX) ?**

---

From what I understand, the only advantage is the ease of use of TensorWatch with notebooks.

Since I don't really work with notebooks, I was wondering if there is any other advantage.

Comment: What kind of advantages are you looking for?

Comment: I can use both. Why would I choose TensorWatch over TensorboardX, since tensorboardX has a bigger community and is around since longer ? That's the question I'm trying to answer.